# Table width exceeds the borders of paper

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table like the below image
[image]

here is the code i have been using:

```
  \documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\DeclareMathOperator\prb{probability}
\DeclareMathOperator\cost{cost}
\DeclareMathOperator\child{child}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}




\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Cost oriented approach in A-ADTree}
   \label{Cost oriented approach in A-ADTree}
  \begin{tabular}{ |m{2.5cm}| m{4cm} | m{7cm} |}
    \hline

    case &  A-ADTree-Structure &  Selection metric \\ 
    \hline
        Disjunctive
    &
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=60mm]{img/conjunction-abstract-form-attack.jpg}
        \end{minipage}
    &
     In cost oriented approach
       \begin{align*}
           \arg \ \min \ \cost \ i   \\
           i \in \ \child(V)
        \end{align*}
        In probability oriented approach
       \begin{align*}
           \arg \ \max \ \prb \ i   \\
           i \in \ \child(V)
        \end{align*}
    \\ \hline
        Conjunctive
    &
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{img/disjunction-abstract-form.jpg}
        \end{minipage}
    &
        $$\ root.cost =\sum_{n=1}^{\ n} child_i.cost $$
        $$\ root.probability= \prod_{n=1}^{\ n} child_i.probability $$
    \\ \hline
           Countermeasure
    &
        \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{img/Cp.jpg}
        \end{minipage}

    & 
         \begin{align*}
           \ \mathrm{Mainpro}_\mathrm{parent} \  is \ probability \ of \ parent \ node \ regardless \ of \ the \ countermeasure\\
           \ \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{parent} \ is \ the \ probability \ of \ parent \ considering \ countermeasure\\
           \ \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{child} \ is \ the \ probability  \ of \  countermeasure \ child\          
        \end{align*}
        \begin{equation}
          \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{parent} = \mathrm{Mainpro}_\mathrm{parent} 
          \times (1 - \mathrm{pro}_\mathrm{child})
        \end{equation}


    \\ \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Almost everything is fine with the table, except its width exceeds the width of the paper.
So, **how can i fit it into the page?**

The below image shows the output[image]